# Clicking span button by id of the parent(with id) - selenium with java

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

Is it possible to click a `span` button which is under the `div` element, also I would like to use the id of the input to make my test stable.

HTML:

```
<div class="idit-go">
<input id="IDITForm@checkRuleVO" class="GoLong align-left idit-go-text" type="text" value="" title="Validation Rule" tabindex="257" name="unknown" ignoredisableenableaction="true" helptextinfo="" disabled="">
<div class="idit-go-buttons">
<span id="IDITForm@checkRuleVOGoClearButtonClear" class="idit-go-clear" title="Clear" tabindex="259" onclick="clearField('IDITForm@checkRuleVOhidden');clearField('IDITForm@checkRuleVO');;">
<span class="fa-stack idit-go-button" value="" title="" tabindex="258" onclick="newPerformSubAction('selectRule',true);">
<i class="fa fa-stack-1x fa-square"></i>
<i class="fa fa-stack-1x fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
</span>
</div>
```

How it looks on screen:

[image: demo]

As you can see the 3 dots button to the right, that is the button I'd like to click. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could identify the `span` that has the `id` attribute and then just use `following-sibling` (from your example they seems to be on the same level).

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='IDITForm@checkRuleVOGoClearButtonClear']/following-sibling::span"));
```

Comment: That id is to click the "X" button, i wish to click on the 3 dots button (second span)

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='IDITForm@requestedAmountVOGoClearButtonClear']/following-sibling::span")).click();`    is working for me , 10x

Comment: How can i can click the 3 dots button without using the "X" button by following sibling span? (some screens might not have the clear button).

Answer (score 1):

using css - `"span[id='IDITForm@checkRuleVOGoClearButtonClear'] + span[class='fa-stack idit-go-button']"`

Comment: does not work - Method threw 'org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException' exception.

Comment: Are you using By.cssSelector() function? I gave a css locator not a xpath locator. Try it on browser console and check first.

Comment: I just tried it again and it is working now, thank you. in further cases is there another way instead of css? any xpath relative?

Comment: for the xpath refer to answer posted by Cosmin above.

Comment: His answer is not valid , i am getting invalidSelectorException error

Answer (score 0):

Okay, no-one got this from what I can see, so I can have a go as well! :)
Here we go Zvika :

```
    element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='idit-go']//span[@class='fa-stack idit-go-button']"));
    element.click();
```

*(locating and clicking an element with span id="IDITForm@checkRuleVOGoClearButtonClear")*

Best of luck man!:)

Comment: Hey,Your answer is for clicking the "X" button,  i was trying to click the 3 dots. 10x

Comment: Hi Zvika, it is the same technique you just need to change the span/id to locate the button you want. I've edited my answer, what about now?